# Calculate new center of a map after zoom-event

Tags: math, openstreetmap

I am trying to figure out how to zoom in to a map, meaning I zoom to the position of the mouse and back again.
For this I have to recalculate the center of the map for every zoom iteration.

I use these formulas for zooming in and it works fine

```
// amount is 1.0 when zooming in and -1.0 when zooming out
newCenterX = (eventPoint.getX() - (mapWidth / 2)) * resolution + center.getX();
newCenterY = ((eventPoint.getY() - (mapHeight / 2)) * resolution / (-amount)) + center.getY();
```

But unfortunately I can't figure out how to zoom out, I just kinda can't get my head around it, so a little help from some math-enthusiast would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you already know https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames?

Comment: @scai I didn't, thanks. But how is that relevant to my question?

Comment: This page contains various formulas. For zooming look at the [subtiles paragraph](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Subtiles).

Comment: The contents of that page are only very, very vaguely related to my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used the "new resolution" for the calculation, after it had already changed, due to the zoom event. Instead I needed the "old resolution" which is half the new resolution.

Also, I had to account for the x-offset from the center, which, when zooming out, is reversed.

So the revised formulas for zooming are

```
Double resolutionFactor = zoomLevels > 0 ? resolution : (resolution / 2);

newCenterX = ((eventX - (mapWidth / 2)) * zoomLevels) * resolutionFactor + oldCenterX;
newCenterY = ((eventY - (mapHeigth / 2)) * resolutionFactor / (-zoomLevels)) + oldCenterY;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not quite clear. I assume that your question is: if I change zoom on the map, where do I have to move the location of the center of the image on the Earth such that the mouse still points to the same position on the Earth.

I'm not aware of a closed formula for anything reasonably close to the real case (i.e. taking into account curvature of the Earth). For a simple case of close enough zoom when you can approximate the surface of the Earth by a local plain rectangle, the question becomes more or less the question of zooming on images.

Let's introduce some notation. `Xr` - real X position on the original image (Earth) in pixels or whatever. `Xi` - position on the scaled image in pixels. `W` - width of the zoomed view in pixels. `Z` - zoom level. Any of those notations might be additionally modified with index and/or suffix `c` meaning "center". Example: `Xrc1` - X position of the center of the image at zoom level #1 on the original image (Earth).

If we want to calculate `Xi` from `Xr`, the formula is:

```
(Xi - Xic)*Z = (Xr - Xrc)
```

And obviously `Xic` is always `W/2`.

Now consider that we have a zoom level `Z1` and mouse points to the `Xi` and the users scales to some other zoom level `Z2`. We want to find where to move `Xrc1` such that for our point on the real image (Earth) `Xr` its projections are the same or `Xi1` = `Xi2`= `Xi`. So

```
(Xi - W/2)*Z1 = (Xr - Xrc1)
(Xi - W/2)*Z2 = (Xr - Xrc2)
```

To solve this for `Xrc2` lets multiply the first by `Z2`, the second by `Z1`

```
(Xr - Xrc1)*Z2 = (Xi - W/2)*Z1*Z2 = (Xr - Xrc2)*Z1
```

So

```
Xrc2 = (Xrc1*Z2 + Xr*(Z1-Z2)) / Z1
```

Or if we name use `K` as the name for difference in scales `Z2/Z1`

```
Xrc2 = Xrc1*K + Xr*(1-K)
```

Sanity checks:

1. If `Xr` = `Xrc1` i.e. mouse is pointing to the center, `Xrc2` = `Xrc1`
2. If the mouse points to the corner and `K` is `0.5` (zoom twice as close) obviously the center should move twice closer to the `Xr`.

Comment: Well, you say my question isn't clear and then you perfectly summarise what I was asking. :D Anyways, I found the answer myself, but thanks for the big effort. I was of course talking about a projection (mercator spherical to be specific) and not about the actual ball that is the earth :) Still a big thanks, quite some stuff to read